# Adding all entries to combobox in linq to sql

Tags: sql, linq, vba, visual-studio-2008, combobox

All i want to do is add each entry of my specific database table to a combo box on form load. This is what i have so far.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles MyBase.Load

    dc = New DataworldDataContext.DataworldDataContext
    Dim countStates = (From z In dc.tblstates Select z).Count
    Dim listStates = (From z In dc.tblstates Select z).ToList

    For i = 0 To countStates - 1
        cmbDealerState.Items.Add(listStates)
        i = i + 1
    Next


End Sub
```

Im getting the error "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set." How can i fix this

Comment: I don't know VB, but the error message seems fairly self-explanatory.  Check in your visual designer to see if DataSource has a value.  Failing that, set it to NULL (or VB equivalent) before trying to addd things to it.

Comment: ok i forgot i had the combobox bound to a table, so i took that off but now i just get "(Collection)" for every item in the combo box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    dc = New DataworldDataContext.DataworldDataContext
    Dim listStates = (From z In dc.tblstates Select z.StateCode).ToList()
    cmbDealerState.DataSource = listStates
```

This worked

Comment: Well I actually meant my answer but hey ho!

Answer (score 0):

For your 2nd problem, the combo box will have 2 properties called DisplayMember and ValueMember.  The display one is the text you wish to display and the value the (usually numeric) value you return when an item is selected.  Simply set them:

```
cmbDealerState.DisplayMember = "myDisplay"
cmbDealerState.ValueMember = "myValue"
```

I am presuming you are using WinForms here.  If its WPF then its a bit more tricky.

## Edit

```
    dc = New DataworldDataContext.DataworldDataContext
    Dim countStates = (From z In dc.tblstates Select z.StateCode).Count
    Dim listStates = (From z In dc.tblstates Select z.StateCode).ToList
    cmbDealerState.DisplayMember = "StateCode"
    cmbDealerState.ValueMember = "StateCode"
```

This still gives me nothing

The problem you have is that you are trying to set DisplayMember and ValueMember to be a ToString representation of your list.  In your database you will have columns that identify the data name, for example

> StateID          StateName
>   1                New York
>   2                Washington

The values you need to set therefore would be:

```
cmbDealerState.DisplayMember = "StateName"
cmbDealerState.ValueMember = "StateID"
```

Obviously these names are made up, but you get the idea.

When I tried this (in C#) I needed to access cmbDealerState.SelectedItem to get the values that had been selected.

Still Nothing

Comment: dc = New DataworldDataContext.DataworldDataContext
        Dim countStates = (From z In dc.tblstates Select z.StateCode).Count
        Dim listStates = (From z In dc.tblstates Select z.StateCode).ToList

        For i = 0 To countStates - 1
            cmbDealerState.DisplayMember = listStates.ToString
            i = i + 1
        Next

This gives me nothing for the combobox

Comment: Display member is the actual name of the column from the database, not it's value.  Using your example you could have something like StateID as your value member and StateName as your display member.  Also it doesn't need to be in the loop - just needs to be set once.

Comment: dc = New DataworldDataContext.DataworldDataContext
        Dim countStates = (From z In dc.tblstates Select z.StateCode).Count
        Dim listStates = (From z In dc.tblstates Select z.StateCode).ToList
        cmbDealerState.DisplayMember = listStates.ToString
        cmbDealerState.ValueMember = listStates.ToString

This still gives me nothing

Comment: dc = New DataworldDataContext.DataworldDataContext
        Dim countStates = (From z In dc.tblstates Select z.StateCode).Count

        For i = 0 To countStates - 1
            Dim listStates = (From z In dc.tblstates Select z.StateCode).First()
            cmbDealerState.Items.Add(listStates)
            i = i + 1
        Next

This gives me 50 "AK" so what do i need to change .First() to, to make it work?

Comment: Change it ToList, remove your loop for countStates and set the DataSource property or cmdDealerState to be listStates.  That should do it.  All you are doing in the code above is finding a count of 50 and then simply displaying your first item 50 times.